# how to make sorting in angular by 2 parameters

Tags: javascript, angular, sorting, mat-table

I want to sort angular table by 2 parameters, for example:

1-2
1-3
1-1
2-9
2-6
2-1

The output will be:
1-1
1-2
1-3
2-1
2-6
2-9

```
this.sortedData.sortingDataAccessor = (item, property) => {
  if (item[property]) {
    return Number(item[property].split('/')[1]) && Number(item[property].split('/')[0]);
  }
};
```

Comment: please add the data, you have, as array literal and the wanted result as well.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in a string array like:
`let myArray =  [ '10/4', '1/1', '2/2', '1/3', '2/1'];`

Then a compare function could sort it as you need:

```
myArray.sort(
   function(a, b) {
      let aX = a.split('/');
      let bX = b.split('/');
      return aX[0] != bX[0] ? aX[0] - bX[0] : aX[1] - bX[1];
   });
```

Assumes the elements are valid numbers delimited by slash.  Will handle number > 9....

Answer (score 0):

in this case :

```
  const x = Number(item[property].split('/')[0]);
  const y = Number(item[property].split('/')[1]);
  return [x,y];
```

1/3 1/33 1/4 1/333 1/5
return like this: 
1/3 1/33 1/333 1/4 1/5

some1 knows why ?

Answer (score -1):

You could use an array of arrays.

```
Array.sort([[1,2],[1,3],[1,1],[2,9],[2,6],[2,1]])
```